# Command that displays a string argument

Tags: command-line

What command will return whatever value is given to it. For example, you would enter the command followed by the string *Hello World* and it will print *Hello World* to the console.

Does such a command exist, and what is it?

Comment: `echo (string)`??

Answer (score 4):

```
echo "Hello World "
```

or

```
printf "Hello World "
```

or (not for newbies):

```
str="Hello World" && "$str" |& grep -o "$str"
```

Comment: +1 for the `printf` and `echo` of course, but your third command does nothing. It would kinda work if `$str` contained no spaces (though it would be printed twice in cases where you get the "Did you mean X from package Y?" message) but as it is, what the shell attempts to execute is `Hello World`, which runs `Hello`, giving it `World` as an argument. Therefore, `$str` will never be present in the output and the `grep` will fail.

Comment: @terdon Thanks and... Oh,... I wanted to be something just for fun. And for me `$str` is present in the output and `grep` doesn't fail; see [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ebSPR.jpg). If it bothers you and if you want to keep an emphasis sober, then edit the answer as you wish, I do not mind.

Comment: OK, that's _weird_. That shouldn't be happening. I am guessing you've changed the value of `IFS` to something that doesn't include spaces. And of course it doesn't bother me, it just fails unless you've changed IFS (can't think of any other situation where it would work). What's the output of `echo "$IFS" | od -a` in the same terminal? Does it contain `sp`?

Comment: @terdon Yes, it does. See [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0fqdF.jpg). And hmmm... This really is not for newbies :D

Comment: Apparently not :). OK, I can get this to work in `zsh` [but not in bash](http://i.imgur.com/N42gmpr.png). One of us must have some setting changed or simply different bash versions.

Comment: @terdon I use `GNU bash, version 4.3.8(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: That's probably it, I'm on `4.2.45`. Guess it's time to upgrade :)

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean echoing?

```
echo GoodMorning
```

prints `GoodMorning`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the `echo` and `printf` shell builtins, if for some obscure reason you cannot use them, you also have `cat`. If you combine it with [Here Strings](http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Here_strings), you can have it print the input you give it:

```
cat <<<"Hello World"
```

In fact, there are many commands that can do this if you twist their arm a little:

```
$ tr '' '' <<<"Hello World"
Hello World
$ sort  <<<"Hello World"
Hello World
$ tee  <<<"Hello World"
Hello World
$ xargs  <<<"Hello World"
Hello World
$ more  <<<"Hello World"
Hello World
$ fold  <<<"Hello World"
Hello World
```

Most of the above (and the list if far from complete) are designed to do something with their input and here we are asking them to basically do nothing, so they print it unchanged.

This answer is mostly for illustrative purposes and is a bit tongue-in-cheek. In real life, just use `printf` or `echo`, that's their job.